# Notification not working on Oreo

Tags: java, android

Notification is showing on android nougat 7.0 and less but not on Orea 8.0
What should i do?
......................................................................................................................................................
Here is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
private final String ChannelId = "Notification";
private final Integer NotificationId = 001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createNotificationChannel();
}


public void sendNotification (View view) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelId);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mBuilder.setWhen(20000);
        mBuilder.setTicker("Ticker");
        mBuilder.setContentInfo("Info");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("New notification title");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Notification text");
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());


}

private void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channelId = "Notification";
    CharSequence channelName = "Some Channel";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use notification channel to create the notification

check if Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O and then use the channel

here is an example I found on the documentation

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

}

then you use builder to build the notification and then you continue as normal

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

This article should be of a good guide to you, according to the new way of implementing Notifications on Android, you need to do that through a Notification Channel

I faced some difficulties implementing this, even though there are so many examples, but here is how it worked for me:

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String channelId;
CharSequence channelName;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    initNotification();
    showNotification();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void initNotification() {
    setNotificationChannel();

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notificationChannel.getId());

    // The methods called for building are following my own needs, change them according to yours
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
        .setContentTitle("Alarm On!")
        .setContentText("Click the notification to dismiss")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        // You can add your intents or actions here
        .setAutoCancel(true);
}

private void showNotification() {
    // You can use a unique alarmRequestCode or just use 1 for testing purposes
    notificationManager.notify(alarmRequestCode, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void setNotificationChannel() {
    channelId = "alarm_channel_id";
    channelName = "alarm_notification_channel";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
}
```

**Please note** that I removed the if statement since I upgraded my whole gradle to work only with the new versions.

**Also** I removed all the snippets of code which you might not need so I can make it easier for you to follow, so if the code doesn't really make sense to you remember that you will need to implement this *within* your own purpose and code!

I hope this will be of a good help :)